# Margins off on tag edits

Tags: bug, tags

While editing tags, it seems to be no longer aligned properly (in fact it's partially hidden:

[image]

How it's supposed to look (how it looks on Meta) 
**It now shows same glitch on Meta** -_-

[image]

Comment: And now that I notice it, I see it **everywhere** and it's so annoying, arghhh. (can't unsee this kinda stuff)

Comment: MSE dupe: [Tags too low while editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307456/307988)

Comment: @Cai yeh it is a dupe... but in our case it's even **worse**!

Comment: Dear SE, please fix.

Comment: @Cai Hey that's me! I've added the screenshot from this site into my post on MSE.